# matplotlib widget with ipywidgets in JupyterLab Desktop

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I have issues when using `%matplotlib widget` in JupyterLab Desktop

First: When I run a `df.plot()` once, it works well, I can see the graph and the cursor, but when I run it again I only got `<Axes: >`.

Secondly: When I run a `widgets.interact()`, results are shown in my log files (and so without a cursor).

I tried `out = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})`

and `with out: display(widgets.VBox([widgets.GridBox(test.children[:nnn-4], layout=widgets.Layout(grid_template_columns="repeat(5, auto)")), test.children[nnn-4], test.children[nnn-3], test.children[nnn-2], test.children[nnn-1]] ))`

The Vbox is shown correctly but the graph is still in my logs instead of my regular panel.

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: You aren't saying if you are running `df.plot()` at the end of a cell or in a separate cell after you already ran it for the previous plot. Second thing, about the `out` stuff. You need to put `out` at the end of you cell where you built the ipywidgets.  See discussion of why that is happening and example [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/matplotlib-draw-in-console-instead-of-cell-output-when-call-in-widget-event-callback/22178/2?u=fomightez). Finally, please actually post code that works and is complete, not just tiny snippets. Even if it is toy stuff that is related but different ...

Comment: <continued> than your own. We cannot reproduce what you are doing with the little your post provided and so a lot of this is asking for clarification and putting 'well if this than that' conditions here. When if you followed the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part under 'Help others reproduce the problem' so those trying to help you could provide specific help and not flounder around trying to learn more from you. The exchange you are currently having with link89 is symptomatic of this, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have a similar problem that figure is draw in console instead of output panel. In my case this issue can be fixed by

```py
plot = df.plot()
fig = plot.figure
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

I think you can get some help from this document: [Interactive figures](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/interactive.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but strangely I have an error:

```TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 3
      1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'widget')
      2 plot=df.plot()
----> 3 fig= plot.figure()
      4 fig.canvas.draw()
      5 fig.canvas.flush_events()

TypeError: 'Figure' object is not callable```

Comment: It is `plot.figure` not `plot.figure()`